# How to return all capital letters in row postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a simple table, primary key and name.
The string always starts with a capital letter but could have more capital letters than just the first character. I want to return all the uppercase characters in the name.

```
select
    (select substring(name, '([A-Z])') name)
from cust
```

This returns just the first capital letter. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex replacement on the name to remove any character which is not an uppercase letter:

```sql
SELECT name, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^A-Z]+', '', 'g') AS caps
FROM cust;
```

Comment: This is perfect, one more question. How can I add a character, if the length of caps is = 1? So T would become TP, but if it were GF it would stay GF? Thanks.

Comment: Use `LPAD()`: `LPAD(caps, 2, 'T')`

Answer (score -1):

This statement will return all the Capital Letters in a particular column.

`select upper(column_name) from table_name;`

Comment: This returns all of the entries in uppercase, I want to return just the uppercase characters from the entry